# Symfony2 with Silex validation still in English

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm building an application in Symfony2. I want to get the translations of validation messages. I read about Silex, but not have idea how to integrate with Symfony2, if i need to install something, or where i need to configure my project. I already have validators.*.xliff file on Resources/translations, but still get validation messages in English. Any idea?

Comment: Silex is a microframework based on Symfony2 components, has nothing to do with translations inside Sf2 itself. Did you read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)?

Comment: My bad. I thought Translations was an implementation given by Silex. Thanks for pointed out the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well first make sure you've correctly set up the default locale for your application (file app/config/config.yml).

Then I strongly advice you to read the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) for a step by step on how translation works in Symfony2.